# EC2 instance won't connect after changing instance type

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I changed one Linux instance type from m3.xlarge to r3.xlarge (moar memory).

After starting again the instance I can't connect with SSH, actually it has no ports opened/with running services so it seems that some services haven't started properly, don't know why. However, it responds to ping so system seems to be running.

If I go back to the original instance type it works again. I repeated the process several times and it always is the same, m3.xlarge works fine but r3.xlarge fails.

I know I can create an image and just launch a new instance and (fingers crossed) it will work, but I'm just curious about this issue, why is this happening and how can it be solved.

Any insights? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This worked fine for me. It took longer for the r3.xlarge to come into service. Did you wait until all status checks were good? Does the system console show anything unusual (compare it to the m3.xlarge launch to find differences)?

Comment: Thanks @jarmod . Apparently there was an extra disk (/dev/xvdf) in the m3.xlarge instance that was not listed in the EC2 console (may be instance store?) although it was included in its /etc/fstab. When changing instance to r3.xlarge the volume disappeared but still was trying to mount it because of fstab... just commented fstab line and voilà.